# Not Able to Copy Paste Text in Web Version of WhatsApp

Tags: firefox, browser, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

I'm using the web desktop version of Whatsapp quite a lot in Firefox, and in the last few days, I noticed that I can no longer send people links. I can still do that through the phone if it's really needed, but that's a bit of a hassle.

I was bothered. but now got the solution.

https://ebuzzpro.com/fix-whatsapp-web-copy-paste-text-not-working/

in the Above link, 4rth step is working perfectly for all Firefox users.

Thanks, community for this.

Comment: Questions should not simply be "this is how to fix the problem". This is a question and answer site, not a forum, it might help to take the [tour] to see how things work here.